# Media query not seeming to work

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Not sure why this isn't working.  Any ideas?

When the screen goes below 700px the background color does not change and the  HeaderImg is still displaying.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style>
    #content {
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    img{
        height:auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        #content{
            background-color:#000;
        }
        #HeaderImg{
            display:none;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
        #HeaderImg{
            display:inline;
        }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <div id="content">
        <img id="HeaderImg" src="LargeBanner_1920x300.png" width="600px" height="300px;"    />
    </div>
```

Comment: could you explain "not working" please.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? What is the expected behavior, and what are you seeing? Can you create a code snippet or a fiddle to illustrate your problem? With 830+ rep points I don't think this is a lot to ask for — you should be well-acquainted with the rules on SO.

Comment: Thank you Terry, your wise words will be taken into consideration..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the second style overrules the first one. After all, less than 700px is also less than 1920px. Swap the two declarations, or specify a min-width as well for the second one, like this;

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
    #HeaderImg{
        display:inline;
    }
}
```

I would choose to specify the min-width. That way it's more clear what your intentions are, and there is no risk of accidentally applying properties to the <= 700px situation, that were actually only meant for the 701px to 1920px situation.

It should still change color, though. And it does, but you cannot see it, because the other issue is that the containing div (#content) will collapse once the image is hidden. It has no height, and therefor is not visible anymore. So to enforce the black bar being visible, you would have to give it an explicit height, or give it content of some sort. If you want it to occupy the space of the image, hide the image by using the style`visibility` instead of `display`. Visibility will show/hide the image, while still preserving the space it occupies in the document, and so the image will still stretch #content.

A dressed down, modified version of your snippet shows this:

```css
#content {
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  /* Just for demo */
  color: red;
}

img{
  height:auto;
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #content{
    background-color:#000;
  }
  #HeaderImg{
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
  #HeaderImg{
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <img id="HeaderImg" src="LargeBanner_1920x300.png" width="600px" height="300px;" alt="Test replacement for missing image">
</div>
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile noting that adding the min-width would definitely be the recommended way to fix this since it makes it much more clear what the programmer is intending to have happen. CSS files can be pretty messy sometimes.

Comment: @charles I completely agree. I thought I had written that as well, but apparently I forgot, so I've added a line about it. Thanks.